# Showing $\left ( a^{-1} ba\right )^{n}=a^{-1}b^{n}a$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Prove that $\left ( a^{-1} ba\right )^{n}=a^{-1}b^{n}a$.

Here's what I have: for positive $n$, $\left ( a^{-1}ba \right )^{n}=a^{n}b^{n}a^{-n}$ by the socks and shoes property.

Any hints for me to go further?

Comment: I don't know what the socks and shoes property is, but what you've stated is false in general.

Comment: I assume $n$ is a positive integer. There is a natural proof by induction. No socks or shoes.

Comment: Yes n is a positive integer.
I identity 2 cases to cover: positive and negative n integers

Comment: The so called socks and shoes property only states that $(xy)^{-1} = y^{-1} x^{-1}$, not $(xy)^{-n} = y^{-n} x^{-n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that
$$(aba^{-1})^n=aba^{-1}\cdot aba^{-1}\cdot \ldots \cdot aba^{-1} = ab(a^{-1}\cdot a)ba^{-1}\cdot\ldots \cdot aba^{-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For $n = 2$ we have $(a^{-1}ba)^2 = a^{-1}baa^{-1}ba$. Now simplify.